# How to use <form> and different options with <select> element to redirect to an external website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a list of options using `<form>` and `<select>`. Researching on the web, I notice that this is used to redirect to sections of the same website, but  I want to make it work so that the user display the options and when they click on submit it redirects them to an external website.

```js
import React from 'react'; 

export default function App() {  
  function handleChange(value) {
    // Do some stuff
  }

  return (
        
       /* what i have tried using onChange */ 
        <form >
          <select value={data} onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
         
          <option value="https://www.example.com">example</option>
          <option value="https://www.example.com">example</option>
          <option value="https://www.example.com">example</option> 
        
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       </form>
       /*      */
  )
}
```

Can I include inside some element like `<option>"onChange method to_redirect='www.google.com'"</option>` or what other way could make the website redirect users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating outside your application has nothing to do with `react-router`.

1. Store the selection in a state variable
2. On submit, use `window.location` to navigate to the chosen option

```jsx
import { useState } from "react";

const options = [
  { value: "https://example.com/", label: "example" },
  { value: "https://example.com/", label: "example" },
  { value: "https://example.com/", label: "example" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = url;
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUrl(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <select required onChange={handleChange} defaultValue="">
        <option disabled hidden value="">
          Select a destination
        </option>
        {options.map(({ value, label }, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={value}>
            {label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit white-https-50m320]

Comment: I was doing some research and they really are different concepts, and the way I phrase the question doesn't cover most of the work you did for me.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster I thought your question was very clear 